# What is Flag Waiting for review

Tags: discussion, review-queues, flags

Hi Please Look below image [image]

In this pic. 33 waiting for review,
my question is who will review this , because my many flags are waiting from a long time..

Comment: Heheh. I've got a bunch too. Nice flagging, BTW.